# Handling connection timeout in GWT

Tags: gwt, timeout, connection

I am using GWT and PHP and communication is via the `RequestBuilder` class,
but I need to handle internet connection present or not and show some message
but `RequestBuilder` class supports `RequestCallback` interface which cannot handle internet
connection present or not. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

[`RequestCallback.sendRequest`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) (or just [`send()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html#send())) throws [`RequestException`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestException.html) - my guess would be that this is the point of failure in case of no net connection. Additionally, the [`RequestCallback`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestCallback.html) you pass to the send(Request) method also has an [`onError`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestCallback.html) method which is:

> Called when a Request does not
>   complete normally. A
>   RequestTimeoutException is one example
>   of the type of error that a request
>   may encounter.

You should probably do some testing yourself to see when the `RequestException` exception is being thrown and when the control gets to `onError` - although, usually you use the same code/method to handle both cases, so it might not matter which handles what, just that together they handle everything :)